# How do you make linebreaks in a HTML textarea result in breaks in the string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML `<textarea>` that I want to be able to make when the user pushes enter in the textarea it results in a linebreak when the string is stored in a variable and printed on the page.

How would I do this? I have seen it done before but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the content of textarea just do this:

```
var text = document.getElementById(textAreaId).value.replace("\n","<br/>");
```

By this way, when you use the variable text, it will be able to break lines in html.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `white-space` property on your output to one of the `pre` values. See here for a list of allowed values and their effects: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_white-space.asp

```
<p style="white-space: pre;">Your text with newlines goes here.</p>
```

Or simply use `<pre>`, a HTML tag that has `white-space: pre;` by default, but this has the inconvenient of changing your font.

I would advise against storing `<br />`s instead of new line characters. If you want to have HTML breaks add them just to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are outputting as HTML, you'll need to replace the line breaks with `<br>` or wrap the text with the [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag.

> The `<pre>` tag defines preformatted
>   text.
>
> Text in a pre element is displayed in
>   a fixed-width font (usually Courier), 
>   and it preserves both spaces and line
>   breaks.